# Mocking XHR call when testing real website using selenium

Tags: selenium, proxy, mocking

I am trying to isolate the UI test which are driven by Selenium(java bindings) from the integration layer. I want to intercept xhr calls going through browser and send back the mocked response.

I have tried to configure proxy(using browsermob) and can see the request goes through it. But now I am not sure how I can return mocked response by intercepting xhr calls.

```
   Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

        proxy.addRequestFilter((request, content, messageInfo) -> {
                if (messageInfo.getOriginalUrl().contains("v1/listings/closing.json")) {
                    String messageContents = content.getTextContents();
                    System.out.println("messageContents:: " + messageContents);

                }
                return null;
        });


        try {
            String hostIp = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy(hostIp + ":" + proxy.getPort());
            seleniumProxy.setSslProxy(hostIp + ":" + proxy.getPort());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DesiredCapabilities seleniumCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        seleniumCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.merge(seleniumCapabilities);

        webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

While testing against real/live website and not local host I want to get the mock response served to UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use proxy. addResponseFilter((response, contents, messageInfo) method

Example :

```
proxy.addResponseFilter((response, contents, messageInfo) -> {
        if (/*...some filtering criteria...*/) {
            contents.setTextContents("This message body will appear in all responses!");
        }
    });
```

Refer to the [blog](https://octopus.com/blog/selenium/15-modifying-http-responses/modifying-http-responses)
and [Github](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/WebDriverTraining/blob/891eb6ec19a7458e4d2cfa23217c25a51ed4a6c7/src/test/java/com/octopus/ProxyTest.java)  You will get example to mock the response.

You may consider Cypress to isolate the UI test from integration tests .It would be easy to mock response using Cypress - Fixture

Comment: what I understood from the blog and github code is this will still require the network calls to got through and then alter the response coming back from external url. Whereas we want to run the test environment less with no network call going to external source point 3 & 4 from blog.   `3.The proxy forwards the request to the external URL. 4. The response from the external URL is passed through a response filter.` I agree cypress and puppeteer tools makes is very easy to intercept xhr and not let if go through.

Answer (score 0):

[Short-circuiting the request with mocked response and not let it pass through using Selenium.](https://octopus.com/blog/selenium/14-modifying-http-requests/modifying-http-requests)

```
 String stubResponse = { mocked json response body };

 proxy.addRequestFilter(new RequestFilter() {
        @Override
        public HttpResponse filterRequest(HttpRequest request, HttpMessageContents contents, HttpMessageInfo messageInfo) {
            if (request.getUri().contains("/v1/listings/closing.json")) {

                //Use DefaultFullHttpResponse for posting the json body
                HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(request.getProtocolVersion(), HttpResponseStatus.OK);
                //Close the connection so it doesn't pass through
                httpResponse.headers().add("CONNECTION", "Close");
                //Specify the content-type and charset
                httpResponse.headers().add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                //other headers if necessary
                httpResponse.headers().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "");
                httpResponse.headers().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                httpResponse.headers().add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","");

                //replace the body 
                HttpObjectUtil.replaceTextHttpEntityBody((FullHttpMessage) httpResponse, stubResponse);

                return httpResponse;
            }

            return null;
        }
    });
```